# nested lists in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, nested-lists

I am new to Ocaml and have defined nested lists as follows:

```
    type 'a node = Empty | One of 'a | Many of 'a node list
```

Now I want to define a wrapping function that wraps square brackets around the first order members of a nested list. For ex. wrap( Many [ one a; Many[ c; d]; one b; one e;] ) returns Many [Many[one a; Empty]; Many[Many[c;d]; Empty]; Many[b; Empty]; Many[e; Empty]].
Here's my code for the same:

```
    let rec wrap list = function
         Empty -> []
        | Many[x; y] -> Many [ Many[x; Empty]; wrap y;];;
```

But I am getting an error in the last expression : This expression has the type 'a node but an expression was expected of the type 'b list. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two matches are not returning values of the same type. The first statement returns a b' list; the second statement returns an 'a node. To get past the type checker, you'll need to change the first statement to read as: `Empty -> Empty`.

A second issue (which you will run into next) is that your recursive call is not being fed a value of the correct type. `wrap : 'a node -> 'a node`, but `y : 'a node list`. One way to address this would be to replace the expression with `wrap (Many y)`.

There will also be in issue in that your current function assumes the `Many` list only has two elements. I think what you want to do is `Many (x::y)`. This matches x as the head of the list and y as the tail. However, you will then need a case to handle `Many ([])` so as to avoid infinite recursion.

Finally, the overall form of your function strikes me as a bit unusual. I would replace `function Empty -> ...` with `match list with | Empty -> ...`.

Comment: Still getting an error after making the changes you suggested. This time, the pattern matching is not exhaustive..

Comment: That's a warning, not an error -- your code can still run without exhaustive pattern matching, but it's not good style nor is it sound programming. It's not exhaustive because you aren't handling the 'One' case. Think about how you'd like to do that.

Comment: Few comments: one, defining a function by pattern matching on an argument without a `match` is perfectly fine and often used, however in this case you should drop `list` from your function definition (you match on the list as an unnamed argument). Two: calling this structure nested list is a bit confusing, I think, what you really defined are trees. Finally three, it is almost never a good idea to ignore warnings on non-exhaustive pattern matching, I'd suggest to handle remaining cases.

Comment: You'll also get a warning since you are matching a list of two elements even though a list can have many elements, one or no elements.

Comment: @nlucaroni not if you match with "Many (x::y)"

Comment: Right, but he didn't. I hadn't seen that part of your answer, and was only responding to his question in the comments.